# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\core\classes\follow.php on line 25

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Everything seems to be working good but i am getting an error:

[image]

I checked for typos in my follow.php and profile.php and even retyped the major part of the code but was not able to figure out the problem.
This is my line 25 of follow.php

```
if($data['reciever'] == $profileID)
```

**Here is my follow.php**

```
    <?php
class Follow extends User
{
    
    function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    public function checkFollow($followerID, $user_id)
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `follow` WHERE `sender` = :user_id AND `reciever` = :followerID");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":followerID", $followerID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    
    public function followBtn($profileID, $user_id)
    {
        $data = $this->checkFollow($profileID, $user_id);
        if($this->loggedIn() === true)
        {
            if($profileID != $user_id)
            {
                if($data['reciever'] == $profileID)
                {
                    //Following Button
                    echo "<button class='f-btn following-btn follow-btn' data-follow='".$profileID."'>Following</button>";
                }
                else
                {
                    //follow button
                    echo "<button class='f-btn following-btn follow-btn' data-follow='".$profileID."'><i class='fa fa-user-plus'></i>Follow</button>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //edit button
                echo "<button class='f-btn' onclick=location.href='profileEdit.php'>Edit Profile</button>";

            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<button class='f-btn' onclick=location.href='index.php'><i class='fa fa-user-plus'></i>Follow</button>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The error states:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

and this is happening on line 25 of follow.php

So, On looking at line 25 of follow.php

```
if($data['reciever'] == $profileID)
```

According to the error, we are trying to access an element in an array but the object is actually a boolean. So, $data must be a boolean. Looking a few lines up, on line 20 there is:

```
$data = $this->checkFollow($profileID, $user_id);
```

So $data is being set by the return value of checkFollow. checkFollow must be giving us a boolean. Looking at checkFollow we see it returns this:

```
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

the boolean must be coming from $stmt->fetch. Let's look at the documentation for this method, which states:

> The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch
> type. In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure.

My DB:

[image]

So that's the source of the error. Why is fetch returning FALSE though?Maybe query is not returning any results. Perhaps there are no rows in the database that match the given parameters.But I don't know how to implement it as i am just beginning in PHP.If someone could show me the syntax for better clarification it would be highly appreciated.!
Thank you!

Comment: [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns `false` when there are no more rows in the result set. Your query is not matching anything

Comment: You should be checking the result of `$stmt->fetch` *before* you attempt to use it. If it is false, you can see what the error is by looking at `$stmt->errorInfo()` (assuming there was an error and the issue is not that the query returned no results). Looking at your code, it looks ok, but perhaps you misspelt `receiver`?

Comment: Since your query will only ever return an array with `$data['reciever']` equal to `$profileID` or `false`, you can safely change to `if ($data !== false)`

Comment: @Nick How do i check the result of  `$stmt->fetch` Do i need to comment my 'followBtn' function in order to check the result?Do i need to replace `return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` by something else?and No, the same spelling of "reciever" has been carried to my db too

Comment: @Ben sounds like it's worth asking a separate question. If you do, you might want to delete this one

Comment: @Phil Okay! I get it

Comment: This is answered and explained better in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058195/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool