# "Following" button not showing up

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, if-statement

**I  am getting this "Follow" Button here**:[image: Follow Button]

**Instead of instead of this "Following" Button.**[image]

**This is my follow.php.**

```
    <?php
class Follow extends User
{
    
    function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    public function checkFollow($followerID, $user_id)
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `follow` WHERE `sender` = :user_id AND `reciever` = :followerID");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":followerID", $followerID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    
    public function followBtn($profileID, $user_id)
    {
        $data = $this->checkFollow($profileID, $user_id);
        if($this->loggedIn() === true){
            if($profileID != $user_id){
                if($data !== false){
                    //Following Button
                    echo "<button class='f-btn following-btn follow-btn' data-follow='".$profileID."'>Following</button>";
                }else{
                    //follow button
                    echo "<button class='f-btn following-btn follow-btn' data-follow='".$profileID."'><i class='fa fa-user-plus'></i>Follow</button>";
                }
            }else{
                //edit button
                echo "<button class='f-btn' onclick=location.href='profileEdit.php'>Edit Profile</button>";

            }
        }else{
            echo "<button class='f-btn' onclick=location.href='index.php'><i class='fa fa-user-plus'></i>Follow</button>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The "Following" button is placed at line 28 in follow.php

```
echo "<button class='f-btn following-btn follow-btn' data-follow='".$profileID."'>Following</button>";
```

Just wanted to tell you guys, I had this line in follow.php earlier.
`if($data['reciever'] == $profileID)`
which is now changed to this `if($data !== false)` I changed it to this because i was getting an
 [ERROR.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770388/notice-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool-in-c-xampp-htdocs-t) , while placing this line-:

`if($data['reciever'] == $profileID)`,But now the error is gone after placing this line-:

```
if($data !== false)
```

My output page does not show any error it just displays a "Follow" button instead of "Following" button.
I want to follow other person's account and want to display the followID,sender,reciever,followOn in my follow table ; which is not happening right now.
**Here is my follow table in my db.**[image]

**This is my profile.php**

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
 if (isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false) {
  $username = $getFromU->checkInput($_GET['username']);
  $profileId = $getFromU->userIdByUsername($username);
  $profileData = $getFromU->userData($profileId);
  $user_id = @$_SESSION['user_id'];
  $user = $getFromU->userData($user_id);
 
  if (!$profileData) {
    header('Location: '.BASE_URL.'index.php');
  }
}

?>

<!--
   This template created by Meralesson.com
   This template only use for educational purpose
  -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title><?php echo $profileData->screenName.' (@'.$profileData->username.')'; ?></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/css/style-complete.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<!--Helvetica Neue-->
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- header wrapper -->
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-left">
            <ul>
                 <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>home.php"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a></li>
                
                 <?php if($getFromU->loggedIn() === true){ ?>
                
                 <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>i/notifications"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>Notification</a></li>
                 <li id="messagePopup"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>Messages</li>
                
                <?php } ?>
            
            </ul>
        </div><!-- nav left ends-->
        <div class="nav-right">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search"/><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <div class="search-result">
                    </div>
                </li>
        <?php if($getFromU->loggedIn() === true){ ?>
                <li class="hover"><label class="drop-label" for="drop-wrap1"><img src="<?php echo BASE_URL.$user->profileImage; ?>"/></label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-wrap1">
                <div class="drop-wrap">
                    <div class="drop-inner">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL.$user->username; ?>"><?php echo $user->username; ?></a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>settings/account">Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>includes/logout.php">Log out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li><label for="pop-up-tweet" class="addTweetBtn">Tweet</label></li>
      <?php }else{
        echo '<li><a href="'.BASE_URL.'index.php">Have an account? Log in!</a></li>';
      } ?>
      </ul>
        </div><!-- nav right ends-->

    </div><!-- nav ends -->
    </div><!-- nav container ends -->
</div><!-- header wrapper end -->
<!--Profile cover-->
<div class="profile-cover-wrap">
<div class="profile-cover-inner">
    <div class="profile-cover-img">
        <!-- PROFILE-COVER -->
        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL.$profileData->profileCover; ?>"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="profile-nav">
 <div class="profile-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <div class="n-head">
            TWEETS
        </div>
        <div class="n-bottom">
          <?php $getFromT->countTweets($profileId); ?>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL.$profileData->username; ?>/following">
                <div class="n-head">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL.$profileData->username; ?>/following">FOLLOWING</a>
                </div>
                <div class="n-bottom">
                    <span class="count-following"><?php echo $profileData->following; ?></span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL.$profileData->username; ?>/followers">
                <div class="n-head">
                    FOLLOWERS
                </div>
                <div class="n-bottom">
                    <span class="count-followers"><?php echo $profileData->followers; ?></span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="n-head">
                    LIKES
                </div>
                <div class="n-bottom">
                    <?php $getFromT->countLikes($profileId);?>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="edit-button">
        <span>
            <?php $getFromF->followBtn($profileId, $user_id);?>
        </span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><!--Profile Cover End-->

<!---Inner wrapper-->
<div class="in-wrapper">
 <div class="in-full-wrap">
   <div class="in-left">
     <div class="in-left-wrap">
    <!--PROFILE INFO WRAPPER END-->
    <div class="profile-info-wrap">
     <div class="profile-info-inner">
     <!-- PROFILE-IMAGE -->
        <div class="profile-img">
            <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL.$profileData->profileImage; ?>"/>
        </div>

        <div class="profile-name-wrap">
            <div class="profile-name">
                <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL.$profileData->username; ?>"><?php echo $profileData->screenName; ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="profile-tname">
                @<span class="username"><?php echo $profileData->username; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="profile-bio-wrap">
         <div class="profile-bio-inner">
            <?php echo $getFromT->getTweetLinks($profileData->bio); ?>
         </div>
        </div>

<div class="profile-extra-info">
    <div class="profile-extra-inner">
        <ul>
      <?php if(!empty($profileData->country)){ ?>
            <li>
                <div class="profile-ex-location-i">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="profile-ex-location">
                    <?php echo $profileData->country; ?>
                </div>
            </li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty($profileData->website)){ ?>
            <li>
                <div class="profile-ex-location-i">
                    <i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="profile-ex-location">
                    <a href="<?php echo $profileData->website; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $profileData->website; ?></a>
                </div>
            </li>
    <?php } ?>

            <li>
                <div class="profile-ex-location-i">
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
                </div>
                <div class="profile-ex-location">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="profile-ex-location-i">
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
                </div>
                <div class="profile-ex-location">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="profile-extra-footer">
    <div class="profile-extra-footer-head">
        <div class="profile-extra-info">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="profile-ex-location-i">
                        <i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile-ex-location">
                        <a href="#">0 Photos and videos </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-extra-footer-body">
        <ul>
             <!-- <li><img src="#"/></li> -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

     </div>
    <!--PROFILE INFO INNER END-->

    </div>
    <!--PROFILE INFO WRAPPER END-->

    </div>
    <!-- in left wrap-->

  </div>
    <!-- in left end-->

<div class="in-center">
    <div class="in-center-wrap">

  <?php

  $tweets = $getFromT->getUserTweets($profileId);

  foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
    $likes   = $getFromT->likes($user_id, $tweet->tweetID);
    $retweet = $getFromT->checkRetweet($tweet->tweetID, $user_id);
    $user    = $getFromU->userData($tweet->retweetBy);
    
    echo '<div class="all-tweet">
            <div class="t-show-wrap">
             <div class="t-show-inner">
             '.((is_array($retweet) && isset($retweet['retweetID']) ? $retweet['retweetID'] === $tweet->retweetID OR $tweet->retweetID > 0 : '') ? '
              <div class="t-show-banner">
                <div class="t-show-banner-inner">
                  <span><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>'.$user->screenName.' Retweeted</span>
                </div>
              </div>'
              : '').'

             '.((!empty($tweet->retweetMsg) && (is_array($retweet) && isset($retweet['tweetID']) && $tweet->tweetID === $retweet['tweetID']) OR $tweet->retweetID > 0) ? '
              <div class="t-show-head">
              <div class="t-show-popup" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'">
                <div class="t-show-img">
                  <img src="'.BASE_URL.$user->profileImage.'"/>
                </div>
                <div class="t-s-head-content">
                  <div class="t-h-c-name">
                    <span><a href="'.BASE_URL.$user->username.'">'.$user->screenName.'</a></span>
                    <span>@'.$user->username.'</span>
                    <span>'.$getFromU->timeAgo($tweet->postedOn).'</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="t-h-c-dis">
                    '.$getFromT->getTweetLinks($tweet->retweetMsg).'
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="t-s-b-inner">
                <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
                  <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner">
                  '.((!empty($tweet->tweetImage)) ? '
                    <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-left">
                      <img src="'.BASE_URL.$tweet->tweetImage.'" class="imagePopup" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'"/>
                    </div>' : '').'
                    <div>
                      <div class="t-h-c-name">
                        <span><a href="'.BASE_URL.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
                        <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
                        <span>'.$getFromU->timeAgo($tweet->postedOn).'</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-right-text">
                        '.$getFromT->getTweetLinks($tweet->status).'
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>' : '

              <div class="t-show-popup" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'">
                <div class="t-show-head">
                  <div class="t-show-img">
                    <img src="'.BASE_URL.$tweet->profileImage.'"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="t-s-head-content">
                    <div class="t-h-c-name">
                      <span><a href="'.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
                      <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
                      <span>'.$getFromU->timeAgo($tweet->postedOn).'</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-h-c-dis">
                      '.$getFromT->getTweetLinks($tweet->status).'
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>'.
                ((!empty($tweet->tweetImage)) ?
                 '<!--tweet show head end-->
                      <div class="t-show-body">
                        <div class="t-s-b-inner">
                         <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
                           <img src="'.BASE_URL.$tweet->tweetImage.'" class="imagePopup" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'"/>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--tweet show body end-->
                ' : '').'

              </div>').'
              <div class="t-show-footer">
                <div class="t-s-f-right">
                  <ul>
                  '.(($getFromU->loggedIn() === true) ? '
                    <li><button><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li>
                    <li>'.((is_array($retweet) && isset($retweet['retweetID']) ? $retweet['retweetID'] === $tweet->tweetID : '') ? 
                    '<button class="retweeted" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class = "retweetsCount">'.$tweet->retweetCount.'</span></button>' : 
                    '<button class="retweet" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class = "retweetsCount">'.(($tweet->retweetCount > 0) ? $tweet->retweetCount : '').'</span></button>').'
                    </li>
                    <li>'.((isset($likes['likeOn']) ? $likes['likeOn'] === $tweet->tweetID : '') ? 
                                    '<button class="unlike-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.(($tweet->likesCount > 0) ? $tweet->likesCount : '' ).'</span></button>' : 
                                    '<button class="like-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.(($tweet->likesCount > 0) ? $tweet->likesCount : '' ).'</span></button>').'
                    </li>    
                    '.(($tweet->tweetBy === $user_id) ? '
                      <li>
                          <a href="#" class="more"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                          <ul>
                            <li><label class="deleteTweet" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'">Delete Tweet</label></li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>' : '').'

                   ' : '<li><button><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li>
                        <li><button><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li>
                        <li><button><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li>
                    ').'

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>';
  }
  ?>
    </div><!-- in left wrap-->
  <div class="popupTweet"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/like.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/retweet.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/popuptweets.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/delete.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/comment.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/popupForm.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/fetch.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/search.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/js/hashtag.js"></script>
 
</div>
<!-- in center end -->

<div class="in-right">
    <div class="in-right-wrap">

        <!--==WHO TO FOLLOW==-->
             <!-- HERE -->
        <!--==WHO TO FOLLOW==-->

        <!--==TRENDS==-->
            <!-- HERE -->
        <!--==TRENDS==-->

    </div><!-- in right wrap-->
</div>
 <!-- in right end -->

        </div>
        <!--in full wrap end-->
    </div>
    <!-- in wrappper ends-->
 </div>
 <!-- ends wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

My profile.php is working completely fine and i just added a line at line 131.Nothing else.This was the line:

```
<?php $getFromF->followBtn($profileId, $user_id);?>
```

So,My problem is that i want "Following" button to appear instead of "Follow" button and when i change this
 `if ($data !== false)` to this `if ($data !== true)` I get my "Following" button in my output but then I don't see any rows at my follow table(followID,sender,reciever,followOn have no values.)

This community has been helping me a lot lately and i am really thankful to each one you!I would really appreciate any suggestion,remark or any kind of help!

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `$data` is, and if  `checkFollow($followerID, $user_id)` produces the correct result manually? Could be something wrong in your query, or the parameters so it always returns false.

Comment: `$data` should return the 'followID' from the 'follow' table but how should i check the value of `$data` and the result of `checkFollow($followerID, $user_id)` can you please show me some syntax which will be used for execution?